# PDO::FETCH_CLASS Arguments

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It's possible to create another instance to send as parameters on the current instance in PDO::fetchAll()?

if \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE is set it will FIRSTLY call the __construct and SECONDLY set the properties. so the values you have passed to the __construct via the array will be overwritten.
But, when it overwritte the values, it doesn't understand the Voucher instance.

It is better illustrate
e.g.

```
<?php
class Voucher {
    private $CD_ID, $CD_VOUCHER, $NR_EXPIRATION, $DT_VOUCHER, $IE_STATUS;
    public function __construct($CD_ID, $CD_VOUCHER, $NR_EXPIRATION, $DT_VOUCHER, $IE_STATUS) {
        $this->CD_ID = $CD_ID;
        $this->CD_VOUCHER = $CD_VOUCHER;
        $this->NR_EXPIRATION = $NR_EXPIRATION;
        $this->DT_VOUCHER = $DT_VOUCHER;
        $this->IE_STATUS = $IE_STATUS;
    }
}
class Authentication {
    private $CD_AUTH, $DT_AUTH, Voucher $CD_VOUCHER, $CD_IP, $CD_MAC, $CD_LOG;
    public function __construct($CD_AUTH, $DT_AUTH, Voucher $CD_VOUCHER, $CD_IP, $CD_MAC, $CD_LOG) {
        $this->CD_AUTH = $CD_AUTH;
        $this->DT_AUTH = $DT_AUTH;
        $this->CD_VOUCHER = $CD_VOUCHER;
        $this->CD_IP = $CD_IP;
        $this->CD_MAC = $CD_MAC;
        $this->CD_LOG = $CD_LOG;
    }
}
public function getAuthentications() {
    try {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `TB_AUTENTICACAO`.`CD_AUTH`, `TB_AUTENTICACAO`.`DT_AUTH`, `TB_VOUCHER`.`CD_ID`, `TB_VOUCHER`.`CD_VOUCHER`, `TB_VOUCHER`.`NR_EXPIRATION`, `TB_VOUCHER`.`DT_VOUCHER`, `TB_VOUCHER`.`IE_STATUS`, `TB_AUTENTICACAO`.`CD_IP`, `TB_AUTENTICACAO`.`CD_MAC`, `TB_AUTENTICACAO`.`CD_LOG` FROM `TB_AUTENTICACAO` INNER JOIN `TB_VOUCHER` ON `TB_VOUCHER`.`CD_ID` = `TB_AUTENTICACAO`.`CD_VOUCHER`;");
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, "Models\\Authentication", array("TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_AUTH", "TB_AUTENTICACAO.DT_AUTH", new \Models\Voucher("TB_VOUCHER.CD_ID", "TB_VOUCHER.CD_VOUCHER", "TB_VOUCHER.NR_EXPIRATION", "TB_VOUCHER.DT_VOUCHER", "TB_VOUCHER.IE_STATUS"), "TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_IP", "TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_MAC", "TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_LOG"));
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
        die($exc->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The result must be:
e.g.

```
Models\Authentication Object (
    [CD_AUTH:Models\Authentication:private] => 2
    [DT_AUTH:Models\Authentication:private] => 2016-03-22 10:44:00
    [CD_VOUCHER:Models\Authentication:private] => Models\Voucher Object (
            [CD_ID:Models\Voucher:private] => 1
            [CD_VOUCHER:Models\Voucher:private] => xYgPB5
            [NR_EXPIRATION:Models\Voucher:private] => 720
            [DT_VOUCHER:Models\Voucher:private] => 2016-03-18 17:00:00
            [IE_STATUS:Models\Voucher:private] => 0
    )
    [CD_IP:Models\Authentication:private] => 10.10.10.10
    [CD_MAC:Models\Authentication:private] => abc
    [CD_LOG:Models\Authentication:private] => 1
)
```

but I get:
e.g.

```
Models\Authentication Object (
    [CD_AUTH:Models\Authentication:private] => 2
    [DT_AUTH:Models\Authentication:private] => 2016-03-22 10:44:00
    [CD_VOUCHER:Models\Authentication:private] => xYgPB5
    [CD_IP:Models\Authentication:private] => 10.10.10.10
    [CD_MAC:Models\Authentication:private] => abc
    [CD_LOG:Models\Authentication:private] => 1
    [CD_ID] => 1
    [NR_EXPIRATION] => 720
    [DT_VOUCHER] => 2016-03-18 17:00:00
    [IE_STATUS] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just keep it simple and define the variable as a class in the class itself. However, I am not sure why you have this issue, perhaps its because you're not attaching a variable to the new class?

If you're using a PHP 5.6+ you can make use of *variable-length argument lists*.
Seeing your code, I think it will boost read-ability by a-lot but the downside is that you need to make sure the correct number of variables are parsed into the constructor.

```
class Authentication {
    private $CD_AUTH, $DT_AUTH, $CD_VOUCHER, $CD_IP, $CD_MAC, $CD_LOG;
    public function __construct($CD_AUTH, $DT_AUTH, array $CD_VOUCHER, $CD_IP, $CD_MAC, $CD_LOG) {
        ...
        $this->CD_VOUCHER = new \Models\Voucher(...$CD_VOUCHER);
        ...
        # or go anonymous in php 7
        $this->CD_VOUCHER = new class(...$CD_VOUCHER){
          function __construct($CD_ID, $CD_VOUCHER, $NR_EXPIRATION, $DT_VOUCHER, $IE_STATUS){
            ...
          }
        }
    }
}

public function getAuthentications() {
    try {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("...");
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, "Models\\Authentication", array("TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_AUTH", "TB_AUTENTICACAO.DT_AUTH", ["TB_VOUCHER.CD_ID", "TB_VOUCHER.CD_VOUCHER", "TB_VOUCHER.NR_EXPIRATION", "TB_VOUCHER.DT_VOUCHER", "TB_VOUCHER.IE_STATUS"], "TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_IP", "TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_MAC", "TB_AUTENTICACAO.CD_LOG"));
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
        die($exc->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: In other case, I already have an instance of Voucher and I'll create an instance of Authentication with this Voucher instance, It works.
But in this case, I'm trying to "automate" the construction of this instance catching from database all data at the same time (Authentication and Voucher params).
So, if I continue to use this construct, do have none way to create a instance of Authentication, instantiating a Voucher, in PDO::fetchAll()? I'll having to create an array from all data fetched and manually create all instances?
Thanks in advance!